# Mysql Output One instead of many

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql data like below

```
country City   Address
    US  NY  Address 1
    US  NY  Address 2
    US  DC  Address 3
    US  NY  Address 4
    US  LA  Address 5
```

Now If I do Like

```
SELECT city from country_list WHERE country='US'
```

The Out put appear like NY, NY, NY I want to print the NY just once how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city from country_list WHERE country='US'
```